# Why install Python packages

Tags: python, anaconda, package

Why we have to install the python packages before using them?

I am currently working on a small python mysql program. What i tried to download the python connector module from mysql webpage and simply unzip it and place it in the same folder of my code.

And I can import the module properly.

So what is the meaning of installing those packages? Can I use those packages like matplotlib, numpy without installing them ?

Is it possible to have all the required packages installed on a folder so that i can move it to another computer and run my program with only CPython installed (I don't want to install any package on this computer)?

Comment: What happens when a Python package you unzip into your project depends on another Python package?

Comment: for mysql, it doesn't depends on other python packages so that's fine.

Comment: That may be true for `mysql-connector`, but it's not true for many other pure-Python packages like `flask`. For example, numpy can't be installed by copy/paste because it compiles tons of Cython code with its `setup.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not that simple :-)

- some packages have dependencies, you also need to download and extract their dependencies (you need pacakge x,and package x uses y) pakcage manager handles that
- some package have some c code (they need to be compiled before use (ujson or postgres module) package manager handles that
- when your share your code instead of sharing dependencies you simply add a file containing the list of dependencies (`requirements.txt`) and other user can simply install all dependencies using package manager

Comment: Is it possible to avoid any installation of the dependencies? I want to zip all the dependencies and my code in a file so that the others can simply unzip it and run my program directly without installing the dependencies.

Comment: check this link http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shipping/freezing/

Answer (score 0):

Installing a python package enables us to use it *anywhere* on our system. If we just place the package in the same directory as our script then it may well work, but only for scripts in that directory.

Some packages also rely on others to function properly, and the installation of a package may well install those pre-requisite packages for you. You may be able to do this manually, but you'd have to put them all in the same directory as your script every time you wanted to run it.

So installing the packages is the easiest way to use them.

You don't *have* to install them, and in some cases you wouldn't install them on your system; if you had split your code across two files and imported one file at the top of the other for example.

Comment: Is it possible to copy a package together with those prerequisite packages to my program folder? I want to move all the required libraries and my code to a new computer with only Cpython installed.

Comment: It very much depends on the package. Your best bet is to simply re-install packages on your new computer as you need them.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you don't really need install package on your system. 
But if you install it, you can use these packages every where on your system.
Also, you can create a `requirement.txt` file to enable install all packages that you need on other computer. You can check this manual https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files